# Android jni lib not found when moving app to system app

Tags: android, java-native-interface, shared-libraries, system

I've been not able to solve my problem, I look around and I couldn't find a good solution.

The things is that I have an Android app that must be system app. I have my own devices so I'm able to install them on system app.

I'm doing this using a pre-installed app on system app. This app takes the .apk file from assets save it on the `data/data` and the move it to `system/app/` folder.

Everything goes good, except when I launch it, it gets an exception `java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError`, this means that the jni lib is not found. Probably because it has not been installed in the `/system/lib` directory.

Anyone know how can I solve this?

I know one solution is to look for the jni lib in the system and move it to `system/lib` but I would like to avoid this.

thank you.